# Streamline of a vector field in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, parametrization

Well we have another homework question from Advanced Calculus that is quite hard to solve, so I thought stackexchange can give me some suggestions on what to do next

**Question:**

> Let $v :\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be the vector field given by
> $v(x,y,z)=[-z,2y,x]$, where    $(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3$.
> Find the streamline through the point $(1, 1, 1)$,
> also known as $p'(t) = v\big(p(t)\big)$,  (i.e., $p(0) = (1, 1, 1)$.

**My Attempt**

First of all, $-dx/z=dy/2y=dz/x$. Hence, we can easily see that $-xdx=zdz$, and if we integrate that, we would get $$-0.5x^2+C_1=0.5z^2+C_2$$ which simply gives $$0.5z^2+0.5x^2=C_1-C_2.$$
We can see that $dz/x=dy/2y$ which gives $2y\ dz=x\,dy$ and if we integrate that again we get $$2y\ z+C_1=y\ x+C_2.$$

I see that we can determine a constant $C_1$ from my point $(1,1,1)$ from that but it doesn't feel right what am I missing and why is it useful that I know these constants.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of finding derivative wrt each other, you need to find it wrt the time.

**Solution:**

First, we let $p(t) \big( x(t), y(t), z(t)\big)$. From the problem statement, we have
\begin{align}
-z(t) = x'(t),\\
2y(t) = y'(t),\\
x (t) = z'(t).
\end{align}
Using Laplace transformation (or any other fundamental methods), we conclude that
\begin{equation}
y(t) = C e^{t}.
\end{equation}
This, together with the fact that $y(0)=1$ concludes that $y(t)=e^{2t}$.

Further, we can derive the following equations using the above ones
\begin{equation}
x''(t) = -x(t),\\
z''(t)=-z(t).
\end{equation}
Hence, again using fundamental ODE solutions, we have
\begin{equation}
x(t)= a_1 \cos (t)+b_1 \sin(t),\\
z(t)= a_2 \cos(t)+b_2 \sin(t).
\end{equation}
This, together with the facts that $x(0)=z(0)=1$, and $x'(t)=-z(t)$, concludes that
\begin{equation}
x(t)= \cos(t)-\sin(t),\\
z(t)=\cos(t)+\sin(t),
\end{equation}
which completes the proof.